# How to sort tables with js/html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table :

```
Name | Department | status
```

I sorted the names alphabetically on click but now I created a dropdown in the status cell which displays values such as Inside/Outside and I want to sort the table when I click on one of those filters I want to only see the people who are in/out. my current JS function :

```
function sortStatusDesc() {
   var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
   table = document.getElementById("myTable");
   switching = true;

   while (switching) {
      switching = false;
      rows = table.rows;

      for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
         shouldSwitch = false;
         x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[2];
         y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("th")[2];

         if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
            shouldSwitch = true;
            break;
         }
      }
      if (shouldSwitch) {
         rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
         switching = true;
      }
   }
}
```

It sorts alphabeticaly.

Comment: Have you considered sorting the data and **then** rendering the sorted data? I'd imagine it would be a little faster as you wouldn't initially have to read all of the data from the DOM.

Comment: You usually don't actually sort rows. If you use a render() function that turns an array of data objects into a HTML table to render the table you have, you can just sort that array of source data using the array.sort() method and then just rerender the table.

Comment: @Shilly I'm glad to see we're on the same page here!

Comment: I m new to javascript so any code would be useful

Comment: @Shilly are you going to post some code or ?

Comment: @Em44 I missed your comment yesterday. I can post some general functions that illustrate what I mean, but since I don't know which data is shown inside the tables, I can't code something that is fully applicable to this situation.

Comment: It's just  some data received from database and controllers not a big deal to call them, if you could post example code that would be great.thanks

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V I would think that with DOM the document *is* the data. To explain, the document occupies memory beyond the rendering, and often is the original copy of the data, not a shadow or a "view" of it. A comparison sort on a table's rows would probably be more effective than replicating row data in an array, sorting it, and re-inserting them. Of course, when your data is an array, then you sort it first, as you said, and insert the rows accordingly.

Comment: @amn Technically it is, but the DOM is very inefficient. So in basic MVC structure, it's easier to think of the DOM as the View and have a JS collection be the data model. The reason for this is that DOM manipulations are among the slowest parts in browser engines. So if you use the DOM as your data store instead of a javascript collection, you run into performance problems very fast when you start queryinging and manipulating nodes that are already rendered.

Comment: @amn If you rerender the entire table completely, you do 1 DOM manipulation, namely replacing the entire table. If you sort the table row by row, as in the OP code, you do multiple DOM manipulations for each row, which can be a magnitude slower, since changing the DOM triggers checks for reflow and repaint, which is by far the most intensive/slowest part of the engine.

Comment: @Shilly DOM reflow and repainting only happens after the script has executed in most browsers, as far as I have known.

Comment: @Shilly Like I said, if the document is the data, then that's the data you sort -- even with DOM performance problems, which is what you want me to believe, the cost of reading the data into array, sorting one, and then rearranging or re-rendering the rows, is hardly going to be faster than e.g. doing an insertion sort on the rows being part of the table.

Comment: @amn Loading the data into an array will happen anyway at startup, else you have to contact the server every time which is even slower. ( single page app vs traditional server rendered website ) So you should only compare sorting the array and rerendering with sorting all the rows inline. One can trigger a couple of reflows for the entire table, the other can trigger several reflows for each row in the table, depending on how exactly the layout and the CSS is. When these reflows happen does not matter, it's the amount of reflows.

Comment: A server does not figure into this, first of all -- we are talking about an already existing table of rows. Wikipedia, for instance, has a table column sorting functionality, and it makes indeed no difference as far as the number of reflows is concerned, whether you offload the row data into an array first, sort the data, and somehow graft the resulting rows back onto the table, whether with a `DocumentFragment` or one-by-one -- sorting rows in place would have been faster than going through with an array, that's my argument. I'll post an answer and then we can measure, by all means.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a  `for loops that force layout & change the DOM are the worst, avoid them.` which is exactly what we have here. A while loop that switches rows around in the live DOM, which may cause reflow or repaint depending on the layout and styling.

Comment: Using a documentFragment will more or less be the same speed. The speed you lose for cloning the live DOM into the fragment should be close to the array sort. I've used both methods extensively, but switched away from documentFragments since it made our templating system more complicated that it should be. Before I used documentFragments or templating, my apps were like several seconds slower.

Comment: The question is about sorting a table with existing rows. I am now very curious about the solution you're advocating for -- given a table and its rows, from what you describe, you will first detach a fragment containing the rows from the table or detach the table itself from its parent (so as not to propagate reflows for the entire document), load the data into an array, sort the array, load data back into the fragment/table, and attach the result back into the document, correct? I mean, please describe the function `sort(table_element, ...)` that the question seems to ask for?

Comment: When you use a documentFragment, you're not going to parse the rows into an array but use the rows like you do. Anyways, as you point out yourself, once you have to sort numbers or dates, you need to know the data types and parse the values, which requires a model of the data and several comparator functions anyway. I just advocate what several frameworks do. Fetch data as json and parse it into a collection, then render the component clientside. Any change in the data model, rerenders the component.

Comment: @Em44 After taking a harder look at your question, you seem to be wanting to *filter* your table, not *sort* it -- you want to hide rows according to the employee "in"/"out" criteria, correct?

Comment: @Shilly I think we have solved two different problems, to be honest. You have shown how to build (or load, or render) a table from a [sorted] data model, and I have shown only how to sort one (the table, that is).

Comment: You can solve both problems with both solutions. Mine requires to use filter on the data and keep the rest the same. Yours requires you to change the function so it takes another parameter function to determine switching rows or deleting rows. I've coded apps in both styles and settled on my solution since it's a nice seperation of concerns. You never have worry about the DOM whatever your transformation might be. It's imho the most important insight I wish people would have taught me when I was starting out since it allowed me to remove like 30% of the codebase.

Comment: @amn yes amn correct

Answer (score 1):

The folllowing snippet shown the sorting on any property.
Clicking on one of the property header changes the sorting.

In the same way, you can create the filtering. Instead of sorting the source_data on a particular property with `data.sort()`, you would `data.filter()` for all the entries that have the correct value.

```js
// Name of the data we're rendering.
const source_name = 'Locations';
// Source data we want to create a table from.
const source_data = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "production hall",  "department": "production",  "status": "inside" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "spare parts room", "department": "production",  "status": "inside" },
  { "id": 3, "name": "warehouse",  "department": "production",  "status": "inside" },
  { "id": 4, "name": "loading bay",  "department": "production",  "status": "outside" },
  { "id": 5, "name": "offices HR",  "department": "administration", "status": "inside" },
  { "id": 6, "name": "offices QA",  "department": "administration", "status": "inside" },
  { "id": 7, "name": "security lounge",         "department": "administration", "status": "outside" }
];
//  Create the table.
//  For this example, we'll use string manipulation to create the HTML.
//  For complex layouts a templating system is better. 
const render = ( name, data ) => {
  // Always include a header for the name.
  // When there's 0 rows, we'll still know what the table shows.
  const labels = data.length
    ? '<tr>' + Object.keys( data[ 0 ]).map( name => `<th data-attr="${ name }">${ name }</th>` ).join( '' ) + '</tr>'
    : '';
  // Actual header for the properties of our data.
  const header = `<tr><th colspan="${ data.length || 1 }">${ name }</th></tr>${ labels }`;
  // One row for each entry in our data.
  const rows = data.map( entry => (`<tr id="entry_${ entry.id }">` + Object.values( entry ).map( value => `<td>${ value }</td>` ).join( '' ) + '</tr>' )).join( '' );
  // Merge it all together.
  const table = `<table><thead>${ header }</thead><tbody>${ rows }</tbody></table>`;
  // Render into the page.
  document.querySelector( '#output' ).innerHTML = table;
};
// Sort of the property.
const sort = ( data, property ) => {
  //  Sort the data on the property in alphabetical order.
  return data.sort(( first, second ) => {
    if ( first[ property ] < second[ property ] ) return -1;
    else if ( first[ property ] > second[ property ] ) return 1;
    else return 0;
  });
};
// Add click events to the header so that clicking a header will sort the rows.
const add_sorting = function( table ) {
  Array
    .from( table.querySelectorAll( 'th' ))
    .forEach( header => header.addEventListener( 'click', create_table ));
};
// Main function
const create_table = event => {
  // We'll reuse this function both manually and through clicking
  const property = event && event.target
    ? event.target.getAttribute( 'data-attr' )
    : event;
  const collection = sort( source_data, property );
  render( source_name, collection );
  add_sorting( document.querySelector( 'table' ));
};
create_table( 'name' );
```

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A table section can easily be sorted according to a *comparator* function (e.g. "is this cell supposed to appear before that cell?", `Math.min`, for example) using any [comparison sort](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) algorithm, here demonstrating the [insertion sort](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), less than 10 lines of actual table sorting code:

```
class InsertionSort {
    static sort_children(parent, comparator) {
        for(let i = 0; i != parent.children.length; i++) {
            const current = parent.children[i];
            let element;
            for(element = current.previousElementSibling; element && comparator(current, element); element = element.previousElementSibling);
            parent.insertBefore(current, element ? element.nextElementSibling : parent.firstElementChild);
        }
    }
}
```

Having a table section (or a table) (the `parent` argument to `sort_children` above) with an amount of rows as children, you can sort it with the `sort_children` method defined above, as long as you yourself rightfully define how your rows should compare:

```
InsertionSort.sort_children(your_table, (row_A, row_B) => row_A.cells[0].textContent < row_B.cells[0].textContent);
```

The above sorts table rows so that the cells of the first column appear in lexicographical order.

The second argument to `sort_children` is the aforementioned comparator function `comparator(row_A, row_B)`, which is expected to return `true` for any two rows it is passed where `row_A` should appear before `row_B`, and `false` otherwise. Since you provide the comparator function, you decide how your rows are sorted.

You can further adapt the comparator function by creating a function that returns a comparator which would be specific to a particular table column, according to a value format (text, number, etc), using the `<` operator automatically (which is defined for `Number` and `String`, among other types):

```
const table_cell_comparator = (column_index, type) => ((row_A, row_B) => type(row_A.cells[column_index].textContent) < type(row_A.cells[column_index].textContent));
```

Then invoking table sorting with a less verbose and more readable expression:

```
InsertionSort.sort_children(your_table, table_cell_comparator(1, Number));
```

The above sorts the rows so that cells of second column with lower numeric value appear before cells with higher numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

"Filtering" a table, as it is called, with existing rows, can easily be done with class toggling, among other things:

```
function filter_table(section, predicate) {
    for(const row of section.rows) row.classList.toggle("filtered", predicate(row));
}
```

What happens above is that rows of an entire table or table section (`section` above) that the `predicate` function considers "filtered", are marked as such by toggling the "filtered" class on these.

The `predicate` function is a function of your own design and choosing that accepts a table row and returns `true` if the row should be filtered or `false` otherwise.

Taking your use case with employee rows, for instance, where let's say the 3rd table cell of every row contains a `select` (drop-down) control with one option for "In" and one option for "Out":

```
<tr><!-- ... --><td><select><option value="in">In</option><option value="out">Out</option></select></tr>
```

You can write the predicate that will filter employee rows according to either "In" or "Out" status ("in" in the example), as follows:

```
const predicate = row => row.cells[2].firstElementChild.value == "in";
```

How you style filtered rows is up to you, you may want to simply hide them, of course:

```
tr.filtered {
    display: none;
}
```

Since the status of each employee effectively changes with the change in drop-down selection, you would be wasting resources by invoking `filter_table` for every such change, which then would go through *all* the rows again. It is then a much better idea to listen on the "change" event that would be fired by the `select` control as it changes its value:

```
table.addEventListener("change", event => {
    if(event.target instanceof HTMLSelectElement) {
        const row = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        row.classList.toggle("filtered", predicate(row));
    }
})
```

You only need to attach a single listener to the entire table -- "change" events *bubble up* the element tree. The `predicate` function defined above is reused, but for the single changed row only.

P.S. Before anyone chooses to jump the wagon so to speak, and recommend use of the `hidden` attribute, I don't consider it appropriate here, without more information in the question -- a filtered row is not an invalid/inapplicable document node, it may only be filtered temporarily, for instance, to aid reading the table according to a variable. Unless you actually want to *remove* such rows, then it's different. I believe the question as it stands asks for "perceptive" filtering.

Comment: this is exactly what I've been looking for,but if you could only help me with the implementation of this certain code because functions are not working(begginer at js sorry)

Comment: Use [MDN](//developer.mozilla.org) to learn JavaScript to a point where the answer makes sense -- the [`for ... of` loop](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), the [`classList`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) property, the [`HTMLTableElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement), what the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM) is and how it works, etc. MDN is a great resource! Be careful with random blogs on Internet -- not all who write know their stuff.